# Querying has_one model with specific attribute value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have two models:

```
class Tree < ActiveRecord::Base                                                 
  has_many :leafs                                                               
  has_one :latest_leaf, -> { order(created_at: :desc) }, class_name: "Leaf"     

  def self.with_connected_latest_leafs                                          

  end                                                                           
end

class Leaf < ActiveRecord::Base                                                 
  belongs_to :tree                                                              
end                                                                             

class CreateTrees < ActiveRecord::Migration                                     
  def change                                                                    
    create_table :trees do |t|                                                  
      t.timestamps                                                              
    end                                                                         
  end                                                                           
end

class CreateLeafs < ActiveRecord::Migration                                     
  def change                                                                    
    create_table :leafs do |t|                                                  
      t.integer :tree_id                                                        
      t.string :state                                                           
      t.timestamps                                                              
    end                                                                         
  end                                                                           
end
```

I want a list of all Trees, with a `latest_leaf` that has the state "connected".

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Rails 4, you can use this:

```
Three.joins(:leafs).where(latest_leaf: { state: "connected" })
```

Comment: I get this error:

`PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "latest_leaf"`

Comment: My mistake. The argument in the `joins` command should be the table name for the `Leaf` model (i suppose it is `leafs`)

Comment: @AndrewVos Did you add `belongs_to` in the other model ?

Comment: @AndrewVos could you post the code from the `Tree` and `Leaf` models?

Answer (score 0):

I can try sub query to get last leaf in each tree. So:

```
Tree.joins("INNER JOIN leafs l ON l.id = (SELECT id FROM leafs WHERE tree_id = trees.id ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1)")
.where("leafs.state = ?", "connected")
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: This selects Trees with connected Leaves that are not the `latest_leaf`.

Comment: what is the real table name `leaves` or `leafs`?

Comment: There is no table, it's a `has_one`.

Comment: I have updated my query. You have to use subquery in joins. I hope it helps you.